# Connecting powershell to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm quite new to both `SQL` and `Power shell`, but I want to run a script which pulls data from a server within `SQL` - Any advice on where to start?

I tried using this as a starting point, but got no luck as it doesn't like my credentials even though they are correct

Test:

```
SqlConnection -ServerName 'END-HDSQ02\DEV4' -DatabaseName 'tbl_cert_expiry' -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Since Powershell V2, you are required to manually load the necessary Snap-Ins;
[Powershell - Invoke-Sqlcmd unable to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762989/invoke-sqlcmd-unable-to-run)

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
```

This is what we use to query a SQL View;

```
[string] $Server= "ServerName"
[string] $Database = "DatabaseName"
[string] $SQLQuery= $("SELECT * FROM schema.TableView order by column")


$data = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Username $username -Password $value1 -Query $SQLQuery
```

Obviously you'll need to pass the connecting user and password as well, but I've omitted them from my example.

Comment: Hello, okay I see what you've done, but when i enter the data I'm looking for, it says that the 'The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program'?

Comment: @Beck123 You need to load in the required snapins. Check here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762989/invoke-sqlcmd-unable-to-run

Comment: I installed the mssql to visual studio code - but it looks like that would only help me if I want to do this through SQL server... however I need to do it through power shell with power shell remotely within it - adding those 'add-PSSnapin' just brings up an error saying that its recognized either

Comment: Solution was solved, apparently my modules were not saving themselves in the place power shell was looking at! thanks everyone :)