# Powershell throws an error "The term 'sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

Tags: powershell

I have to schedule a jams job for sending a report to a client. But my job failed and I get an error in the log file

> The term 'sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

This is my PowerShell script:

```
param (
    [string]$DatabaseServer = "COREP02P.centiv.com",
    [string]$SFTPPath = "/home/cdibrm02/",
    [string]$SFTPServer = "test-externalftp.prudential.com",
    [string]$SFTPCredential = "PrudentiaReport-SFTP-Test",
    [string]$JamsServerName = "jams01d.brandmuscle.local"
)

Import-Module JAMS

$localDataDirectory = "C:\temp\$(New-Guid)"
New-Item $localDataDirectory -itemType directory

$Prudential_EmailCampaignReport = "$localDataDirectory\Prudential_EmailCampaignReport.txt"
$Prudential_EmailCampaignReportFile = "$localDataDirectory\Prudential_EmailCampaignReportFile.txt"

# run reports
sqlcmd -S $Databaseserver -E -d "CentivPos" -Q "Exec [dbo].[Prudential_EmailCampaignReport]" -o $Prudential_EmailCampaignReport -W -s "," -h -1

(get-content $Prudential_EmailCampaignReport | select -Skip 1) | select-string -pattern "Warning" -notmatch |  select-string -pattern "affected" -notmatch  | select-string -pattern "--------" -notmatch  | set-content $Prudential_EmailCampaignReport

$Data = Get-Content $Prudential_EmailCampaignReport -Raw
$Cleanup = $Data.Replace("`n`r`n","").Replace("`n`n","").Replace("`r","")
$Cleanup = $Cleanup | Set-Content $Prudential_EmailCampaignReport -Force

#get filename
$filename = (Get-Content $Prudential_EmailCampaignReport -First 1).Substring(44, 45)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825030/invoke-sqlcmd-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet)

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the executable path for `sqlcmd` and add it to your user path environment variable. See [this link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Alternatively you can create the path to the exe as a variable for your script, like so:

`$sqlCmd = "C:\Path\To\sqlcmd.exe"`

And then you could call it like so in your script

```
$sqlcmd -S $Databaseserver -E -d "CentivPos" -Q "Exec [dbo].[Prudential_EmailCampaignReport]" -o $Prudential_EmailCampaignReport -W -s "," -h -1
```

Comment: Could we use Invoke-Sqlcmd at the place of $sqlcmd

Comment: Yes you could.  You would need to make sure the SQLPS module is loaded, as well as rewrite the line of code so that the parameter names match what the command expects.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively , we can use Invoke-sqlcmd to run any sql statements.

sqlcmd is an alias name for Invoke-sqlcmd

Ex:

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Databaseserver -Database $database -Query $sql -QueryTimeout "2000"